Demonstrating that an Induction Hypothesis is too weak.
My background is in Computer Science. Proofs by induction are ubiquitous here, especially in programming languages.
As a running example, let us take proving things about the natural numbers. To prove that a predicate P holds for all natural numbers (∀n:Nat, P(n)), you prove P(0) (base case) and ∀n:Nat, P(n) => P(n+1) (inductive step).
In many cases however, we may need to generalize the predicate P and prove a stronger statement by induction. That is, to prove ∀x : Nat, P(x), we prove ∀x : Nat, Q(x), which is stronger (Q(x) => P(x)).
Here, we say that the induction hypothesis is not strong enough. In a nutshell, my question is whether we can make this statement precise.
Here's what people seem to do:

Try to prove ∀n:Nat, P(n)
Prove the base case.
Get stuck on the inductive step.
Conclude that the hypothesis is too weak.

'Getting stuck' seems like a "I know it when I see it" situation, and I was wondering if it even makes sense to make this 'getting stuck' notion precise.
Something naive like showing that P(n) => P(n+1) is invalid is not possible because it cannot be invalid if ∀n,P(n) is valid.

Can you show an example of such a thing happening?

One possible way to make it precise would be to say that you cannot prove $P(n) \to P(n+1)$ without using induction on $n$ again, but that might not suit all situations.

@NaïmFavier Yes, that makes sense and I was thinking about that as well. I was wondering if other people have wondered about this question before too..

Somewhat related: since you mention your background is in CS, this article by Mike Schulman discusses the specific case of "getting stuck" when proving properties of programming languages/type theories by induction, and then gives a more principled approach via categorical gluing to derive the correct "motive" of induction. (This assumes familiarity with category theory)

I personally call this "Stronger Induction". It is esp used in contest-math settings where you've not given the statement to induct on, and sometimes what you're asked to prove is too weak. The typical example is proving inequalities via induction of the form $LHS_n \leq RHS$, where the $LHS_n$ is an increasing function. The idea is to find a $LHS_n \leq RHS_n \leq RHS$ that will allow us to perform the induction. Another (not great) example is proving facts about recurrance relations, where fact 1 on $a_n$ implies fact 2 on $a_{n+1}$, and vice versa. You can't just induct on fact 1.

You ask if it makes sense to formalize 'getting stuck'. The answer is positive, but unfortunately the resulting questions about precisely which arguments require strengthening the hypothesis are difficult to settle. I'll first have to give a brief introduction to the axioms of arithmetic, so that I can reformulate your intuitive question as a precise one about models of (fragments of) arithmetic.

Questions of the form "can we prove result $X$ without using machinery $M$?" tend to be hard. In some of these cases, the difficulty lies in formalizing what it means to prove something without machinery $M$, in a way that matches the intuitions of muggles non-proof-theorist mathematicians. "Can we prove Cantor's theorem without diagonalization" is an example of this sort of difficulty: a proof theorist might insist that diagonalization is just reuse of a variable on two sides of a relation symbol in a set comprehension, but other mathematicians will inevitably disagree, without offering an alternative definition that better formalizes their intuitions.
In other instances, we have (sometimes multiple) relatively clear formal definitions available, and the real challenge lies in saying anything substantive about any of them. Your question about induction falls under the latter case. Proof theorists and other mathematicians tend to agree that "we invoke an induction axiom" encapsulates what we mean by induction adequately; but as we will see, questions about required uses of induction axioms lead to difficult mathematical problems.

Usually, we formulate the elementary theory of arithmetic in the language $(+,\cdot,S,0)$ using the universal closure of the seven basic axioms

$Sx \neq 0$ (zero is not the successor of any number),
$Sx = Sy \rightarrow x = y$ (the successor function is injective),
$x=0 \vee \exists y. Sy = x$ (every number is either zero or the successor of some other number)
$x + 0 = x$ (recursive definition of addition, base case)
$x + Sy = S(x + y)$ (recursive definition of addition, inductive case)
$0 \cdot x = 0$ (recursive definition of multiplication, base case)
$Sy \cdot x = (y·x) + x$ (recursive definition of multiplication, inductive case)

along with infinitely many more axioms constituting the so-called induction schema, stating that the universal closure of
$$\left (\varphi(0) \wedge \forall k. \varphi(k) \rightarrow \varphi(Sk)\right) \rightarrow \forall n. \varphi (n)$$
are all axioms for any well-formed formula $\varphi(-)$ of the language $(+,\cdot,S,0)$.
Basically, all instances of the induction schema together affirm that induction is applicable across any formula. Accordingly, we can control the types of induction we allow by restricting the induction schema to a subset of "allowed formulae". This turns your intuitive question into the following precise question about formal logic:

Consider a model $G$ of the seven basic axioms in the language $(+,\cdot,S,0)$ of arithmetic. How much of the induction schema can $G$ satisfy without satisfying $\forall x. P(x)$? In particular, can $G$ simultaneously satisfy all induction axioms of low complexity, along with all the induction axioms in which $\varphi(x)$ is some subformula of $P(x)$?

If the particular question admits a positive answer, then one cannot prove $\forall x. P(x)$ without strengthening the induction hypothesis.
Pinning down the "all induction axioms of low complexity" part requires some technical finesse. For example, if you have an argument that seemingly uses a straightforward induction, but makes use of the commutativity of multiplication, then that technically requires an auxiliary induction to prove. But this auxiliary proof can be given by using induction on very simple formulas, so-called bounded formulas in the arithmetical hierarchy, and you can take the "induction axioms of low complexity" clause to mean precisely these formulas.
If, however, your $P(-)$ is also of this very simple sort, you need to introduce more fine-grained restrictions than what the arithmetical hierarchy allows, and this can get fairly technical and difficult.

So what's the catch?
Well, the definition above reduced your broad, intuitive question into a precise, well-defined question about models of bounded arithmetic... a subject infamous for its intricate, impenetrable constructions and profound complexity.
Long story short, while formulating the question is not that hard, providing specific examples of arguments that one provably can't carry out without strengthening the induction hypotheses is very challenging. You might find slightly simpler subproblems using this approach, but ultimately the topic remains highly technical.
Finally, one could also try other reformulations of this question. For example, one could ask about provability in certain cyclic proof systems: I won't go into this, except for noting that there is a CS angle here, in that it's closely related to the existence of proofs in a certain simple recursive form in Agda and similar proof assistants. Alas, the technical model constructions you face in the end remain fundamentally similar to those encountered in the fragments-of-arithmetic formulation above.
Svejdar has a very brief introduction to bounded arithmetic to get you started if you want to dig deeper. Pudlak has a talk about working with weaker fragments.

you are simplifying to much (and overlooking something fundamental) there are many predicates where $ \forall x ( P(x) \rightarrow P(x+1) ) $  fails (notice the quantifier)
So any proposition were $ \forall x ( P(x) \rightarrow P(x+1) ) $ fails will do.
was thinking about
P(x) as  x is either a prime number or a composite number.
it is (I think) quite impossible to proof P(x+1) from P(x)
but still I heard it say that  every number is either a prime number or a composite number.
the trick is just that induction requires some way to deduce P(x+1) from P(x) and if that way doesn't exsist (or isn't known) induction fails.
another option is maybe the Goldbach's conjecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture
because  P(x+2) doesn't follow in any known way from P(x) , so it is still an open question.

This is not answering the question.

Your $P(x)$ is true for any $x$, so it is easy to prove $P(x+1)$ "from" $P(x)$ just by ignoring the irrelevant hypothesis.
